# Regular expression for e-mail validation not working

Tags: asp.net, regex

I've set up a regular expression validator to validate all e-mail addresses that are entered into a textbox on one of my forms the only problem is it's not working in a weird case.

Here's my code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEmail1" runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="rgv1" runat="server"
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
ControlToValidate="tbEmail1" ErrorMessage="Invalid email address" />
```

The case that this is not working is when an e-mail address is entered like this

> jamie-taylor-@hotmail.co.uk

Now I wasn't aware that e-mail addresses could be set up in this way but i've just set one up and it seems to be fine except the fact that I cannot input this into my form without it telling me it's invalid

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's enhance the regex :

```
\w+([-+.']\w+[-]*)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

### edit

for @Sjoerd :

```
\w+([-+.']\w+[-]*)*@\w+([-.]*\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

Comment: @Sjoerd try this `\w+([-+.']\w+[-]*)*@\w+([-.]*\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*`

Comment: Follow Sjoerd's link in his answer, don't reinvent the wheel, terribly.

Answer (score 2):

[Comparing E-mail Address Validating Regular Expressions](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php). This page has both regexes and e-mail addresses to test with.

It is generally better to make your regex not very strict. Better to have one or two e-mails bounce back than that your customers can not create an account.

Answer (score 0):

use the below expression may help you

```
 \w+([-+.']\w+[-])*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([.]\w+)*
```